# Set Root Page as Modal in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am building a Xamarin app, where in my portable logic, I have my `app.cs` file, launching a `HomePage`. At the moment this is done ith the following code:

```
public App ()
{   
    MainPage = new NavigationPage (new HomePage (Adapter, IsLoggedIn));
}
```

However, I don't want the "title" bar to show at the top of this page, so would like to launch this page with a `PushModalAsync` command, so that `HomePage` is a Modal Page. However, the following line doesn't work, as in `app.cs`, `Navigation` is not recognised.

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new HomePage());
```

Is this possible and if so, how do I get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can set the root page of your App to be a modal.  However, if you just want to hide the navigation bar, you can do this in the page you want it hidden on:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's your main page you can just set the page itself. Say "HomePage" inherits from "ContentPage":

```
MainPage = new HomePage (Adapter, IsLoggedIn);
```